# Youtube iFrame inside another iFrame

Tags: html, css, iframe, youtube

On my site i have banners at the top, the banners are iFrame elements. 
I now need to add a youtube video, inside the banner iFrame.

How do i add the youtube iframe inside another iframe? 
The problem is, i can easily add the youtube video to the banner, but i can't change the size of the youtube video without changing the whole iframe.

I can easily make the whole thing in HTML but it has to be an iframe. And this is where i get stuck.

Comment: do you have control over the source of the first iframe?

Comment: Yes i do, i have full control over the original iframe, it's simple, it's just a picture with text on.

Comment: It'll be helpful to know why you definitely need an iframe for your banners. Also providing a working jsfiddle or live example would help to understand your question.

Comment: I'm working for a major retail store, and the only thing supported in the banners is iframes. I can not do anything except iframes.

Comment: I made a sketch of the result i would like, let's say the banner is 400px*200px, i then need a small youtube player inside the banner, on lets say, 100px*100px.

http://peecee.dk/uploads/052013/ifrtmae_test.png

Comment: all iframes are, are a way of loading an html document within another html document so if you have full control of the source you should be able to just change it and add your youtube iframe into the source of document the first iframe is pointing at

Comment: from what you are saying and the diagram is showing though you don't need iframes, just styled divs

Comment: Thank you Pete, so to be clear, i can make the site in divs, and then add the iframe tags, and it should work?

Comment: I don't see what you need iframes for.  what does the current src for the advert iframe say?  you need to change the document that it is pointing at to add your iframe for youtube.  If you could include an example of the code for your advert iframe it would help out

Answer (score 0):

You could put the iframe next to your iframe for your banner, then put a position absolute and position it within your iframe. Its dirty but doable.

```
<iframe style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;" src="" /></iframe>
```